# Can't click textbox after validation fails

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, binding

I'm working on trying to implement validation in WPF, and running into an issue where I can't click on or change the value of a textbox after validation fails.

I have a User class (which implements IDataErrorInfo), which contains the following relevant code:

```
public virtual string Error
{
    get
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public virtual string this[string name]
{
    get
    {
        string result = null;

        if (name == "uFirstName")
        {
           if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.uFirstName))
            {
                return "Must enter a first name!";
            }
         }
         return result;
     }
}
```

Then, over in my MainWindow code-behind, I have this code to hookup my combobox:

```
comboBox1.ItemsSource = Users; //Users is a collection of Users
```

Finally, in my MainWindow xaml, I have this:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBox1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource userTemplate}" />
<TextBox Name="textBox1" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=comboBox1,
    Path=SelectedItem}" Text="{Binding Path=uFirstName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
    NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
```

And indeed, the validation does fire when I delete the text and the textbox gets a nice red border. However, the changes are still sent back to Users (uFirstName gets set to nothing!). Even worse though, I now cannot edit the value in that textbox *unless* I **tab back into it**.

What is needed to make sure the value isn't sent back if it isn't valid, and allow the textbox to be edited if is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

The IDataErrorInfo implementation is only there to report errors. You should implement your verification in the uFirstName property. If you don't think a certain verification on a property is true for all instances, you should start looking into `ValidationRule`. This is a better way of implementing Validation in WPF. ValidationRule will not set value to the source, if the validation fails.

The textbox might be acting strange because of a system level style? Not exactly sure on why you are  having trouble there.